# Line Messaging Push API not working

Tags: rest, api, line-api

While sending message through line API I am getting the error:

> {"message":"The property, 'to', in the request body is invalid (line: -, column: -)"}

The command I used:

```sh
curl -X POST \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer **********' \
-d '{
    "to": "******",
    "messages":[
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world1"
        },
        {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Hello, world2"
        }
    ]
}' https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push
```

Comment: You should use markdown to format your question so that it's easier to read. Alternatively you can use the editor on SO. Click on the `{}` icon after highlighting the code part and it'll get formatted better.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you forgot to change property `to` to recipient ID.

ID looks like `U206d25c2ea6bd87c17655609a1c37cb8`.

---

Note that you have to make sure your account have `PUSH_MESSAGE` access, or you will get following error when you try to access the API.

```js
{"message":"Access to this API is not available for your account"}
```

You can check usable API in Bot settings under your account page.

[image: Bot settings page]

Comment: Hi @osk2. How about if in Usable APIs, `PUSH_MESSAGE` is not listed. How to enable it? On my account there only `REPLY_MESSAGE`

Comment: The only way I know to do this is creating a new `Messaging API` service with **Start using Developer Trial** option

Comment: Thank you @osk2. I just realize that I using Free subscription. Many thanks